# Sql server 2008 codeSnippets or templates advice needed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

There are many tools out there some free and some not that offer a codesnippet facility.
For some reasons in the company I work for they dont want to install or buy any third party stuff.

I need to work with just sql server 2008.
Is there a way to modify the templates so that when you choose create new SP it loads the custom sp.
In a nutshell I would like to know either if I can have code snippets in sql server 2008 without using third party tool or how i can modify templates.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server Mangement Studio has always supported the use of templates that can serve as "snippets" - see the [MSDN docs on how to use Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174169.aspx).

This is built-in, free, no cost, no install - just use it. It's quite useful to [create your own set of scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166841.aspx) as custom templates for those that you use frequently.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no snippet facility EG type something in the editor and it shows in the editor like sql prompt etc..

Comment: @devnet247: no, something like this is *not* available in SQL Server Mgmt Studio - for that, you need additional tools like SQL Prompt

Answer (score 0):

yes

- [One example of stored proc template](http://sharpdudes.com/blog/post/2008/08/StoredProcedureTemplate.aspx)
- [Snippets](http://ctrlshiftb.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/snippets-for-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/)
- [SQLServerPedia](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/sql-server-management-studio-tips-and-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

In Management Studio, View -> Template Explorer (or just CTRL + ALT + T)
In the template explorer, you just locate the template you want to change, right click and "Edit"

Comment: thanks for your reply.Is there a facility like typing something like EG "createsp" in the editor and my template appears?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and I doubt it. You can however change the default template for when you right click and choose "New Stored Procedure" in Object Explorer